# Do I need to set the Application Key in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my app.php file I have this configuration:

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

Do I need to seet the encription key (the one that's on the env.php file) or now.
The one that's in the env.php file is longer than 32 characters.

And also in the app.php for configuration is it better if I set the debugging value to true:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set application key two ways.

```
1. php artisan key:generate
```

Or

```
2. Edit config/app.php and change 

'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'XXXXXXX') // key
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to set the key. You can do it easily by:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

of course, after fresh install composer does it for you and you don't have to change anything. You only need to generate the key if you're installing from github/without the use of composer.

Comment: I did and it says that the key from the env.php file is set successfully.

Do I need to add that key to the app.php?

Comment: No, Laravel gets the value from .env file. Function "env" reads settings from .env file, so you don't have to mess with app.php on every server. You shouldn't change these values in app.php unless you really know what you're doing. Changes should be made only to .env file.

Comment: So, if I'm instaling with Composer I don't need to run the php artisan key:generate command?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have laravel application installed. The key is generated and updated in `.env` file. No need to set it up in `app/config.php`.